# WCF makes all types strings

Tags: c#, wcf

I have this method in my service

```
    public Guid GenerateToken(Guid application, String email, String password, String mac, String ip)
    {
        var users = new Users();
        if (users.SelectByEmail(email)?.Password != password) return Guid.Empty;

        var userTokens = new UserTokens();
        return userTokens.CreateToken(email, application, mac, ip);
    }
```

with this in my servicecontract

```
    [OperationContract]
    Guid GenerateToken(Guid application, String email, String password, String mac, String ip);
```

however, when I build and look in the service xml I see this:

```
<xs:element name="GenerateToken">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element xmlns:q1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" minOccurs="0" name="application" type="q1:guid"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="password" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="mac" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ip" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

When I use the service in another project it also says I have to use strings as parameters. It used to work but I must have changed something somewhere that made it act up as it did. I have not been able to find the problem in the past couple of hours that I have looked at it.

My test application also says that the return type of the method is a string, while it clearly is a guid.

What could I have done that it does these things and how can I fix it?

Comment: No, the first parameter is a guid... Look again

Comment: All variables are `string` except the `guid`, which is a `guid` in the xml too.

Comment: I don't see any return type for `GenerateToken` in your XML given. Everything else is exactly as it is in your method though.

Comment: Damn, you're right... In my blindness I read what I wanted to read in the xml. But, in my test app it still says that the first parameter and return types are strings... Now that I look at it again in the xml the return type is a guid, but in my test app it is still a string. I have tried to rebuild and readd the service multiple times already.

Answer (score 0):

Your test app may be caching some service metadata which incorrectly defines the Guid field.

I suppose it's also possible that your test app somehow does not have access to the schema which defines your guid type (guid is not a native XSD type), and is somehow gracefully recovering from this by falling back to xs:string, but this is far fetched.

Regardless, one way to avoid this is to delete the auto-generated service proxy in your test app and consume the service directly using WCF channel stack.

```
var proxy = new ChannelFactory<IMyServiceContract>("<endpoint name in client config>");
var myGuid = proxy.GenerateToken(...);
```

If this doesn't tickle your fancy, have you tried completely removing all the autogenerated proxy code and re-adding it. Are you sure you're pointing to the current version of the service when you are adding it?